# Brightscript plugin: How to access user variables in processEvent

Tags: brightscript

I'm following allong the example of the "plugins and parsers" pdf
(found here: [using plugins and parsers technote (PDF)](http://brightsignbiz.s3.amazonaws.com/documents/BrightAuthor%20Plugins%20and%20Parsers.pdf) )

How do i access user variables (read, write) in the processEvent function?

```
Function pizza_ProcessEvent(event As Object)
  if type(event) = "roAssociativeArray" then
    if type(event["EventType"]) = "roString" then
      if event["EventType"] = "SEND_PLUGIN_MESSAGE" then
        if event["PluginName"] = "Pizza" then
          pluginMessage$ = event["PluginMessage"]
          print "received pluginMessage ";pluginMessage$
          return true
        endif
      endif
    endif 
  endif
  return false
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be in `m`, which is the BrS equivalent of `self`/`this`.

I.e. when for a PizzaBuilder's instance `pb` the method (or event; "member function" really)
`pb.processEvent()` is called, inside it a magic variable `m` points to `pb`. So what you asked for - based on PDF sample - is probably `m.userVariables`.

Disclaimer: i know Roku's B/S, not BrightSign; they are closely related.

Comment: ah, yes, the magic ``m`` :-) i found a better example in the heartbeats plugin. Indeed, in the initialize function you create an object and add the uservariables to it. https://github.com/brightsign/heartbeats/